Prove sum of powers for Golden Ratio
On the Wikipedia for the Golden Ratio I stumbled onto this formula:

I tried to prove it using induction:

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ show:
\begin{equation}
\varphi^n = \varphi^{n-2-2\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor}+\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor} \varphi^{n-1-2i}
\end{equation}
Start $(n=1)$:
\begin{align}
\varphi^1 &= \varphi^1+0\\
&= \varphi^{1-2-2\cdot (-1)}+\sum_{i=0}^{-1}\varphi^{1-1-2i} \\\
&= \varphi^{1-2-2\cdot \big\lfloor \frac{1}{2}-1 \big \rfloor}+\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{1}{2}-1 \big \rfloor}\varphi^{1-1-2i} \\\
\end{align}
Step:
\begin{align}
\varphi^{n+1} &= \varphi \bigg(\varphi^{n-2-2\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor}+\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor} \varphi^{n-1-2i} \bigg) \\
&= \varphi^{(n+1)-2-2\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor}+\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor} \varphi^{(n+1)-1-2i} \\
&= \varphi^{(n+1)-2-2\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor}-\varphi^{(n+1)-1-2\big (\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor +1\big)} +\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor+1} \varphi^{(n+1)-1-2i} \\
&= \varphi^{(n+1)-2\big (\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor +1\big)}-\varphi^{(n+1)-1-2\big (\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor +1\big)} +\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor+1} \varphi^{(n+1)-1-2i} \\
&= \varphi^{(n+1)-2\big (\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor +1\big)} (1-\varphi^{-1})+\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor+1} \varphi^{(n+1)-1-2i} \\
&= \varphi^{(n+1)-2\big (\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor +1\big)} \varphi^{-2}+\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor+1} \varphi^{(n+1)-1-2i} \\
&= \varphi^{(n+1)-2-2\big (\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor +1\big)}+\sum_{i=0}^{\big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor+1} \varphi^{(n+1)-1-2i} \\
\end{align}
The proof would be done if I could show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \big\lfloor \frac{n}{2}-1 \big \rfloor+1 = \big\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}-1 \big \rfloor$
But this is false for even numbers, like 2 for example:
\begin{equation}
\bigg\lfloor \frac{2}{2}-1 \bigg \rfloor+1 = \big\lfloor 0 \big \rfloor+1 = 1 \neq 0 = \bigg\lfloor \frac{1}{2} \bigg \rfloor = \bigg\lfloor \frac{3}{2} -1 \bigg \rfloor = \bigg\lfloor \frac{2+1}{2} -1 \bigg \rfloor
\end{equation}
How can I fix my proof?

The claim is about two equations in $m$, obtained by setting $n=2m+2$ and $n=2m+3$. Make this pair of claimed properties of $m$ what you're trying to prove by induction, and start again. In other words, use expressions for $\varphi^{2k+2},,\varphi^{2k+3}$ (the case $m=k$) to prove expressions for $\varphi^{2k+4},,\varphi^{2k+5}$ (the case $m=k+1$).

@J.G. I thought about something similar: Set $n = 2l$ for even numbers and $n = 2l+1$ for odd numbers with $l \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and then do induction two times with $l=0$ and $l \to l+1$. But I'm curious if it can be done by using induction only once.

It can if you do it my way, yes. It's just that the single inductive step has an induction hypothesis with an "and" in it.
